# How to use ROHM LB202VL display (on BP-006LH-GC board) with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, display

I got this 8-unit, 7-segment, 2-digit display board with 24 pins and I am wondering how I can interface with this from my Arduino Uno.

The board is labeled ROHM BP-006LH-GC and it has 8 units of the LB202VL LED display. Please see these photos of the board:

[image: Front of ROHM BP-006LH-GC board]

[image: Back of ROHM BP-006LH-GC board]

[image: Side of ROHM BP-006LH-GC board]

I found the datasheet for the LB202VL unit and I have been trying to make an independent unit on the board to work but I haven't been successful in setting its display.

The datasheet for the LB202VL unit can be found here: http://pdf.datasheetarchive.com/datasheetsmain/Datasheets-27/DSA-525461.pdf

Can anybody help me explain how I can work with this and set the display from my Arduino? After having attempted a few times I feel a little lost with this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+multiplexed+seven+segment+display

Comment: Get a power supply of 5v or so, and a 680 ohm resistor, two lengths of wire, and probe pins until you figure it out.  You can later try a slightly smaller resistor close to the data sheet maximum, especially when you start sequencing the LEDs.

Comment: 8 pins for the 7 segments and the dot (Anodes). 16 pins for the 16 digits (Cathodes). Looking at the traces I can't see any pattern in how they are connected. Just use Chris's suggestion.

Comment: A multimeter set to diode test will also work. I use it to test for working 7-segs when I shop.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar display, and I found the wiring by inspection and trial and error:

The display consist of 8 pairs of digits (LB-202VL, common cathode).

If contact points are numbered from 1 to 24 from left to right then
the common cathodes for the digits D1-D16 and the segments D.P. and 'a' - 'g' are noted below.
If you i.e. connect 1 to GND and 7 to + then segment 'c' of the first digit will be on. You have to multiplex the digits in order to use it.

1. D1
2. D2
3. D3
4. D4
5. D.P.
6. D5
7. c
8. D6
9. e
10. D7
11. a
12. D8
13. g
14. D9
15. d
16. D10
17. f
18. D11
19. b
20. D12
21. D13
22. D14
23. D15
24. D16